# how to properly split express routes into separate files?

Tags: express, routes

I have read through posts about this issue but I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

What I would like is to separate each of my route (login and register for now) into their own separate file, reference those files in routes/user/index, then use that in server.js. This is what I have now:

- server.js
- ROUTES

  - USER

    - index.js
    - LOGIN

      - index.js
    - REGISTER

      - index.js

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

(...)

app.use("/user", require("./routes/user"));

(...)
```

**routes/user/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/login", require("./login"));
router.use("/register", require("./register"));

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/user/login/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", async (request, response) => {
(...)
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/user/register/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", async (request, response) => {
(...)
});

module.exports = router;
```

All I get is a 404 error. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, after a few more hours of googling & trial/error I finally figured it out. For some reason I didn't find earlier this [setup guide](https://github.com/searsaw/express-routing-example) but it was pretty much what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create chainable route handlers for a route path by using `app.route()`

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/login").post((request, response) => {
  //Your code goes here
});

module.exports = router;
```